# How to insert image on the right side of the table?

Tags: tables, diagrams

I have a problem, I need to put this graphic on the right side of the table on this page.
I tried many times and I could do only this case. Probably, I have to raise picture up, so other graphic can also be on this page. However, I don't really know how to do it.

Thanks for advices!

[image: File I got]

```
\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
%\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{c}{0.5\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{file1.pdf}
    \caption{}
    \label{2.32}
    \end{wrapfigure}

$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \text{(Nr. 2.202)}  \\ 
    \hline
    0 & 0  \\ 
    \sfrac{\pi}{12} & \cdots  \\
    \sfrac{\pi}{6} & \sfrac{\pi}{12} \approx 0,26 \\
    \sfrac{\pi}{4} & \sfrac{\pi}{8} \approx 0,39 \\
    \sfrac{\pi}{3} & \sfrac{\pi}{6} \approx 0,52 \\
    \sfrac{\pi}{2} & \sfrac{\pi}{4} \approx 0,79 \\
    2\sfrac{\pi}{3} & \sfrac{\pi}{3} \approx 1,05 \\
    3\sfrac{\pi}{4} & 3\sfrac{\pi}{8} \approx 1,18 \\
    \pi & \sfrac{\pi}{2} \approx 1,57 \\
    5\sfrac{\pi}{4} & \cdots \\
    4\sfrac{\pi}{3} & \cdots \\
    3\sfrac{\pi}{2} & 3\sfrac{\pi}{4} \approx 2,36 \\
    5\sfrac{\pi}{3} & \cdots \\
    2\pi & \approx 3,14 \\
    5\sfrac{\pi}{2} & \cdots \\
    3\pi & 3\sfrac{\pi}{2} \approx 4,71 \\
    4\pi & 2\pi \approx 6,28 \\
    \cdots & \cdots \\
    \hline
\end{array}$
\qquad
 \begin{wrapfigure}{c}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{file.pdf}
        \caption{}
        \label{2.33}
        \end{wrapfigure}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass..` through `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem. What is `file1.pdf` and `file.pdf`? It seems you just want maths on the left and a graphic on the right so no need to provide reams of code for the maths or graphic.

Comment: With the package graphicx, you can use example-image-a  and example-image-b instead of file.pdf and file1.pdf

Comment: Where is the other figure in your output image?

Comment: I don't think `wrapfigure` is useful here. It needs a paragraph of text next to it, but in your example the paragraph consists of just the `tabular`. A `tabular` counts just as one character in a paragraph, so there actually is nothing to wrap (the table can't be wrapped). Besides, from your description it isn't really clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want both figures to be positioned to the right of the table?

Comment: Sorry, other graphic was on the other page and I didn't do screenshot of it. And thank you for advice  'use example-image-a and example-image-b'! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to use `wrapfigure` would be something around these lines

```latex
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{<width>}
  % Image 1

  % Image 2
\end{wrapfigure}
Paragraphs containing text to wrap around images.
```

If I understand, you would expect LaTeX to create an area to the right with both images together. The code below is a solution based only on minipages, which should be sufficient in this case. I would also arrange images vertically because the table is tall.

I added a couple of supporting packages, such as `adjustbox` to let images have a top alignment, and `caption` to format captions. On the other hand, `kantlipsum` and `showframe` are just for the demo code: the first adds dummy text and the other draws a red reference frame around a page.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[aboveskip=3pt,belowskip=0pt]{caption}

\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum}   % Dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]%

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \vspace{\intextsep}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{|>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$}|}
      \hline
      & \text{(Nr. 2.202)} \\ 
      \hline
      0               & 0  \\ 
      \sfrac{\pi}{12} & \cdots  \\
      \sfrac{\pi}{6}  & \sfrac{\pi}{12} \approx 0,26 \\
      \sfrac{\pi}{4}  & \sfrac{\pi}{8} \approx 0,39 \\
      \sfrac{\pi}{3}  & \sfrac{\pi}{6} \approx 0,52 \\
      \sfrac{\pi}{2}  & \sfrac{\pi}{4} \approx 0,79 \\
      2\sfrac{\pi}{3} & \sfrac{\pi}{3} \approx 1,05 \\
      3\sfrac{\pi}{4} & 3\sfrac{\pi}{8} \approx 1,18 \\
      \pi             & \sfrac{\pi}{2} \approx 1,57 \\
      5\sfrac{\pi}{4} & \cdots \\
      4\sfrac{\pi}{3} & \cdots \\
      3\sfrac{\pi}{2} & 3\sfrac{\pi}{4} \approx 2,36 \\
      5\sfrac{\pi}{3} & \cdots \\
      2\pi            & \approx 3,14 \\
      5\sfrac{\pi}{2} & \cdots \\
      3\pi            & 3\sfrac{\pi}{2} \approx 4,71 \\
      4\pi            & 2\pi \approx 6,28 \\
      \cdots          & \cdots \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \captionof{table}{The caption}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,height=3.5cm}
    
    \includegraphics[valign=T]{example-image-a}%
    \captionof{figure}{A}\label{2.32}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}%
    \captionof{figure}{B}\label{2.33}
  \end{minipage}%
  \vspace{\intextsep}
\end{minipage}

\kant[1][2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much! My problem is solved :)